# How to Refresh fragment from another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, refresh

**My Problem is:**

I have 3 classes:

- MainActivity.java
- ContactFragment.java
- AddNewContactActivity.java

In `MainActivity`, it's content `ContactFragment`. From `MainActivity`, I click on `Add Button` to go to `AddNewContactActivity`

**I want When I click on `Save Button` in `AddNewContactActivity` and go back to `MainActivity`, I must update `ContactFragment` with `new data`**

How can I do this? Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

When starting AddNewContactActivity start it with startActivityForResult. AddNewContactActivity can pass back result code representing success and cancellation. When the starting activity receives success result code it can reload/ refresh its content.

Ref: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult`.

```
private static int final ADD_CONTACT_CODE = 1;

// MainActivity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ADD_CONTACT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // data is the contactIntent you set in AddNewContactActivity
            // update your fragment here with that data
        }

    }

// addContactButton in MainActivity
onClick {
    startActivityForResult(addNewContactIntent, ADD_CONTACT_CODE);
}

// AddNewContactActivity
// call this when you're finish adding contact
void finishAddContact() {
    Intent contactIntent = Intent();

    // add your added contact here
    contactIntent.putExtra("added contact", addedContact)

    setResult(RESULT_OK, contactIntent);
    finishActivity(ADD_CONTACT_CODE); // this will close this activity returning to the MainActivity and calling its onActivityResult
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but  I met a new problem: RecyclerView(contains Contacts) do not refresh to see new contact

Comment: Are you getting the right contact data from onActivityResult?